# Trying to run Meteor after updating to 0.9.4 on ubuntu getting errors like TypeError: Cannot call method 'add' of undefined

Tags: meteor

I am new-bee to meteor, i am struggling to run this.

```
kanna@kanna-VPCEB3QFX:~/Desktop/testhtml5/testhtml5/testHTML$ sudo meteor

[sudo] password for kanna:`enter code here`
[[[[[ ~/Desktop/testrschtml5/rschtml5/testHTML ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
W20141017-13:19:19.659(5.5)? (STDERR)
W20141017-13:19:19.737(5.5)? (STDERR) /home/kanna/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1atmdl8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20141017-13:19:19.738(5.5)? (STDERR) throw(ex);
W20141017-13:19:19.739(5.5)? (STDERR) ^
W20141017-13:19:19.739(5.5)? (STDERR) TypeError: Cannot call method 'add' of undefined
W20141017-13:19:19.739(5.5)? (STDERR) at app/server/route.js:8:15
W20141017-13:19:19.740(5.5)? (STDERR) at app/server/route.js:930:3
W20141017-13:19:19.740(5.5)? (STDERR) at /home/kanna/Desktop/testhtml5/testhtml5/testHTML/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:168:10
W20141017-13:19:19.740(5.5)? (STDERR) at Array.forEach (native)
W20141017-13:19:19.741(5.5)? (STDERR) at Function..each..forEach (/home/kanna/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.1atmdl8++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20141017-13:19:19.741(5.5)? (STDERR) at /home/kanna/Desktop/rschtml5/rschtml5/testhtml5/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
=> Exited with code: 8
```

The code for route.js is

```
Meteor.Router.add({
'/output/login': function () {
/some thing here
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   You have a better chance of getting answers if you format your question in a way that's easy to read.

Comment: I think `meteor/iron-router` doesn't have a method `Meteor.Router.add`.If you are using Iron-Router here is the github page link https://github.com/eventedmind/iron-router/ there you can find the docs for 0.9.* and 1.* versions depending on what version you use

Comment: Using old iron-router? Try `meteor add iron:router` instead

Comment: @imslavko i have already done this but no use still get the above error

Comment: @iAmME, I went through above link, i changed Meteor.Router.add to meteor.Router.route then also i got same error message TypeError: Cannot call method 'route' of undefined
W20141027-00:29:45.483(5.5)? (STDERR)     at app/server/route.js:8:15
W20141027-00:29:45.483(5.5)? (STDERR)     at app/server/route.js:933:3
please help me to solve i am struggling from long time..

Comment: Are you trying for server side routing?

Comment: yes server side routing, well iam not sure, this developed by some one else, i see this routing code in route.js inside server folder.